# i deleted the tomcat folder in etc/init.d

Tags: tomcat

while installing tomcat again

```
systemctl status tomcat8.service
● tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-08-18 00:00:29 IST; 16s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 8552 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 18 00:00:29 aditya-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
Aug 18 00:00:29 aditya-HP-Pavilion-Notebook tomcat8[8552]:  * tomcat8 is not installed
Aug 18 00:00:29 aditya-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 18 00:00:29 aditya-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
Aug 18 00:00:29 aditya-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 18 00:00:29 aditya-HP-Pavilion-Notebook systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

how to fix this?
i also want to install tomcat8 again in my ubuntu

Comment: Try this: sudo apt install --reinstall tomcat8

Comment: E: Internal Error, No file name for tomcat8:amd64